# C++ range-based for() loop with std::map

Tags: c++, dictionary, for-loop

I have these types:

```
using key = std::string;
using stop_container = std::unordered_map<key, stop_o>;

using stop_name_const_reference = const std::string &;
using stops_const_reference = const stop_container &;
using timetable_const_reference = const timetable &;
using stop_const_reference = const stop_o&;

class timetable {
    public:
    stop_container timetable_stops;
    trip_container timetable_trips;
};
```

these methods:

```
stops_const_reference stops(timetable_const_reference tt)
{
    return tt.timetable_stops;
}

stop_name_const_reference stop_name(stop_const_reference st)
{
    return st.first;
}
```

Then my problem is with range for loop:

```
for (auto&& stop : stops(tt))
    {
        auto&& stop_name_ = stop_name(stop);
    }
```

I can rewrite it like this for better understanding:

```
for (auto&& stop : const std::unordered_map<key, stop_o> &)
    {
        auto&& stop_name_ = stop_name(stop);
    }
```

For method stop_name I need `const stop_o` as an argument, but from the loop I get `const std::pair<const key, stop_o>`. I know that this is how the maps are working there, but can I somehow achieve to have only the value from pair there AND WITHOUT CHANGING the for loop at all?

Comment: Are you looking for `for (const auto& [_, stop] : stops(tt))` or `auto&& stop_name_ = stop_name(stop->second);`?

Comment: for (const auto& [_, stop] : stops(tt))

Answer (score 4):

```
for (auto const& [key, stop] : stops(tt))
{
    auto&& stop_name_ = stop_name(stop);
}
```

this uses a technique known as "structured bindings" to turn the pair into two references to the elements of the pair.

Prior to structured bindings, you could have done

```
for (auto const& elem : stops(tt))
{
    const auto& stop = elem.second;
    auto&& stop_name_ = stop_name(stop);
}
```

If you want to keep the body and initial statement of the for loop unchanged, you would have to change `stops`.

If `stop_o` is free to copy:

```
std::vector<stop_o> stops(timetable_const_reference tt);
```

that shouldn't be expensive to write.

If not, you have to get fancy.

```
template<class T>
struct pseudo_pointer {
  T t;
  T* operator->() { return std::addressof(t); }
};

template<class F, class It>
struct mapping_input_iterator {
  using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;
  using reference = std::invoke_result_t<F, typename std::iterator_traits<It>::reference>;
  using value_type = std::decay_t<reference>;
  using difference_type = typename std::iterator_traits<It>::difference_type;
  using pointer = pseudo_pointer<reference>;
  F f;
  It it;
  mapping_input_iterator& operator++() {
    ++it; return *this;
  }
  mapping_input_iterator operator++(int) {
    auto retval = *this; ++(*this); return retval;
  }
  bool operator==(mapping_input_iterator const& other) const {
    return it == other.it;
  }
  bool operator!=(mapping_input_iterator const& other) const {
    return !(*this == other);
  }
  reference operator*() const {return f(*it);}
  pointer operator->() const {return {f(*it)};}
};
template<class F, class It>
mapping_input_iterator(F, It)->mapping_input_iterator<F, It>;

template<class It, class Sentinal=It>
struct range {
  It b;
  Sentinal e;
  It begin() const { return b; }
  Sentinal end() const { return e; }
};
template<class It>
range(It, It)->range<It, It>;
```

then write some utility functions on top of the above work:

```
template<class C>
auto get_keys( C const& c ) {
    auto key_getter = [](auto const& pair)->decltype(auto) { return pair.first; };
    using std::begin; using std::end;
    mapping_input_iterator b{ key_getter, begin(c) };
    mapping_input_iterator e{ key_getter, end(c) };

    return range{std::move(b),std::move(e)};
}
template<class C>
auto get_values( C const& c ) {
    auto value_getter = [](auto const& pair)->decltype(auto) { return pair.second; };
    using std::begin; using std::end;
    mapping_input_iterator b{ value_getter, begin(c) };
    mapping_input_iterator e{ value_getter, end(c) };

    return range{std::move(b),std::move(e)};
}
```

now we can do this magic:

```
auto stops(timetable_const_reference tt)
{
  return get_values(tt.timetable_stops);
}
```

there are similar utilities in `boost` and in `std::range` (in a recent C++ standard) if you are afraid of the above code, which is reasonable.

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/chWo4T).

---

Note that I did a bunch of stuff above "properly" in a few small ways, when a slightly simpler version would have worked.

To do a `for(:)` loop you don't need an actual iterator, you just need one that can convince the `for(:)` loop generated code.  I actually wrote a real iterator wrapper.

Also

```
template<class It>
range(It, It)->range<It, It>;
```

intentionally doesn't let you deduce the sentinal type as different than the iterator; that is too easy to get wrong by accident, if you want a sentinal you have to pass it in explicitly.  Despite this my `range` supports a seperate end sentinal, because I'm writing it **right** not simply.

OTOH, I should probably make the value/key getters not be an anonymous local lambda, so people can name the range type that `get_keys` returns without doing a decltype.  Oh well.

Comment: what if I cant change the loop at all? I can only change the methods and containers

Comment: then obviously you can't change what it assigns the looped pairs to...

Comment: @Rikib161999 You cannot change what code does without changing code **somewhere**.  What are you allowed to change?  If you can't change anything, then no, you can't change what stuff does without changing anything.  Do you want to change the function `stops` and its return value only or something?  (I'd view that as changing the loop, but maybe you don't)